# generator based on the LFSR

Tags: c#, algorithm, lfsr

Implement a pseudo-random number generator based on the LFSR method. The polynomial should be provided by the user as a parameter. The program should generate bits "indefinitely" until the user stops the algorithm.

Web app in C#

```
aspx.cs:
 
protected void generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string polynomial = tb_polynomial.Text;
  UInt32 tab = Convert.ToUInt32(tb_polynomial.Text, 2);
  UInt32 periodsToDO = UInt32.Parse(tb_NumberofCycles.Text);
  UInt32 start_state = tab;
  UInt32 lfsr = start_state;
  UInt32 period = 0;
 
  do {
    UInt32 lsb = lfsr & 1;
    lfsr >>= 1;
    if (lsb > 0)
      lfsr ^= tab;
    ++period;
    if (lfsr == start_state)
      lfsr = start_state;
  } while (period < periodsToDO);
  lb_generator.Text = "Made for " + polynomial;
}


.aspx:
 
        
<h2>xx</h2>
<div>
  <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Enter a polynomial"></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="tb_polynomial" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <br />
  <asp:Button ID="generuj" runat="server" Text="Generate" OnClick="generate_Click" />
</div>
<div> Number of cycles to be performed: <asp:TextBox ID="tb_iloscCykli" TextMode="Number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Label ID="lb_generator" runat="server" Text="..."></asp:Label>
</div>
```

I don't know if I fulfilled the last requirement correctly: the program should generate bits "indefinitely" until the user stops the algorithm. Can I get some tip?
And is the overall solution in line with the assumptions?